# Is the /data dir encrypted when android encryption is enabled?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I am interested to know if the `/data` dir is encrypted when android encryption is enabled?

Specifically, I have an app that utilises a native shared object library

I believe this file resides in `/data/data/<package_name>/lib/`

My phone is not rooted so I do not believe I have permissions to view this dir

But I would like to know if it gets encrypted?

Comment: initial investigation suggests answer is yes - see https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/encryption/